# Erro .class expected

Tags: java, string, funções

É suposto o programa pedir um numero entre 1 e 12.(Ainda nao cheguei a parte de certificar que está entre 1 e 12 mas essa é a mais facil.No entanto é suposto escrever o codigo atraves de funçoes (nao que eu veja muito sentido ser por funçoes num exercicio assim).Mas pelo meu raciocinio nao funciona. Deixo aí. Além disso alguem sabe alguma pagina ou me pode explicar como funciona os tipos de função? do género eu só conheço a **public static void** e a **public static final** e **public static String**(se é que existe mesmo).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Idique um número entre 1 e 12");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    System . out . println(num + "Correponde a :" + mesesdoano);
}
public static String mesesdoano()
{
    String meses = ("janeiro  fevereiromarço    abril    maio     junho    julho    agosto   setembro outubro  novembro dezembro "); //vai relacionar o número introduzido com a formula //
    Substring=(int (numero*9)-9,int numero*9);// vai buscar á string meses a palavra correspondente de acordo com o número.Cada mês ocupa sempre nove espaços para através dessa "formula" ir buscar a palavra.
    return substring;
```

Comment: Sua duvida é sobre o que é `public static void main(String[] args)` ou qual o problema do código(que alias, tem muitos)?

Comment: Esta linha `Substring=(int (numero*9)-9,int numero*9);` não é valida. Estava a tentar fazer o que especificamente ?

Comment: @Articuno é sobre as classes das funçoes e tambem sobre o codigo.

Comment: Peço desculpa @Isac vo adicionar uns comentarios ao codigo

Comment: Sua duvida não está clara, por favor, seja mais especifico.

Comment: @Articuno a primeira é que o codigo nao realiza o pretendido. A segunda é que nao sei o que colocar apos public static ____ de acordo com o que quero fazer nessa função e se existe alguma "lista" que ajude.

Comment: Acredito que o erro `.class expected`, seja por que você está atribuindo um `int` à uma classe, na linha `Substring=(int (numero*9)-9,int numero*9);`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam entao o que devo atribuir? é porque sem o int tambem nao dá

Comment: posso fazer uma resposta com um método que faça o que tu deseja, mas de modo diferente

Comment: Se achar que vaime ajudar eu agradeço muito. É porque eu sou muito novato nisto e ainda estou a aprender os basicos.

Comment: Como você está compilando e executando, @Phil ?

Answer (score 0):

Criei uma função que retorna uma `String` (mes do ano), funciona da seguinte forma:

```
public String mesesDoAno(int i) {
    //Crio uma variável ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> meses = new ArrayList<>();
    //Adiciono os meses do ano à variável 
    meses.add("janeiro");
    meses.add("fevereiro");
    meses.add("março");
    meses.add("abril");
    meses.add("maio");
    meses.add("junho");
    meses.add("julho");
    meses.add("agosto");
    meses.add("setembro");
    meses.add("outubro");
    meses.add("novembro");
    meses.add("dezembro");
    //Retorno a String (mes) correspondente ao número que o usuário escolheu - 1, porque o array começa no índice 0, ou seja, 0 = janeiro, 1 = fevereiro...
    return meses.get(i-1);
}
```

Para chamar basta enviar um `int`:

```
mesesDoAno(mesQueOUsuarioDigitou);
```

Da forma como tu fez, não sei bem o que tu queria mas acho que se trocar essa linha:

```
Substring=(int (numero*9)-9,int numero*9);
```

Por essa:

```
String substring = meses.Substring(int (numero*9)-9,int numero*9);
```

Supondo, claro, que o restante do código esteja correto, irá funcionar

Comment: Eu teria usado um vetor propriamente dito, um mapa, ou até mesmo `switch case`.

Comment: Ah, para usar na `main`, o método `mesesDoAno` precisaria ser estático

Comment: na verdade nem precisa criar o método só colocar o conteúdo dentro do main e usar `meses.get(i-1)`, sendo `i` o valor que o usuário digitou, também são outras possibilidades

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por conseguir resolver de maneira bem simples até. Mas foi baseado no primeiro problema que coloquei. Acabou ficando assim e corre sem problemas:

```
    System.out.println("Indique um número entre 1 e 12");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();        
    final String meses = ("janeiro  fevereiromarço    abril    maio     junho    julho    agosto   setembro outubro  novembro dezembro ");
    String mesesdoano =meses.substring ((num*9)-9,num*9);
    System . out . println("Correponde a :" + mesesdoano);
```